# GWT - How set compiler output for several modules into the same folder

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-compiler

I'm using 2 gwt modules (each has an entry point class set) that extend a base module containing shared static files (css, images). When I compile these modules for deployment, gwt compiler creates 2 folders "module1" and "module2" in my "war" folder and duplicates the static files in the base module.
Is there a way to set the compiler to write the public output into same folder, so that the created modules javascript files are create like modules/module1.nocache.js and modules/module2.nocache.js ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use gwt compiler to do that, but you could set an ant or maven task:

If you use ant, put something like this in your ant file:

```
<copy todir="target/.../module1" >  
    <fileset dir="target/.../module2" includes="**"/>  
</copy>
```

If you use maven:

```
 <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <configuration>
            <tasks>
              <echo message="Customizing droid app for ${customer}"/>
              <copy todir="target/.../module1" >  
                 <fileset dir="target/.../module2" includes="**"/>  
              </copy>
            </tasks>
          </configuration>
          <phase>prepare-package</phase>
          <goals><goal>run</goal></goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
 </plugin>
```

Comment: I believe that is not a solution: first of all i would need to move the files (otherwise, what would be the point of all this ?) and second, if i move them, the second module will not have the resources built with the correct relative links.

Comment: This solution works well. I have many projects doing this. The second module does not know nothing about the `/module2` since all its resources are relative to from where the `module2.cache.js` file is downloaded.

Comment: Hmm, I use Eclipse (with Google plugin) to deploy to App engine, so can can I run an ant script after GWT compilation and before deployment to google App engine ?